# python compare and replace strings in txt file with filenames

Tags: python, list, replace, compare, filenames

I have a file `data.txt` and a `sounds` folder with `mp3` music files.

`data.txt` contains a list of `filenames.mp3` (in `random` order) from the sounds folder and from other folders.

I've converted the `mp3` files in the `sounds` folder to `wav`, and I want to replace the `filenames.mp3` in the `data.txt` with the same `filenames.wav` from `sounds` folder only.

Ex: `D:\sounds\data.txt` contains the lines

```
`01_Track.mp3 24
01_artist_name-song_name.mp3 80
02_Track.mp3 16
02_artist_name-song_name.mp3 16
03_artist_name-song_name.mp3 24
01_random_song.mp3 33
02_random_song.mp3 12
03_Track.mp3 90
03_random_song.mp3 36`
```

D:\sounds\ now contains the following files

```
`01_Track.wav
02_Track.wav
03_Track.wav`
```

In `D:\sounds\data.txt`I want to replace `.mp3` extension of the matching filename from `D:\sounds\` with `.wav`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os

with open("data.txt") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        line = line.strip()
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join("sounds", line)):
            os.rename(os.path.join("sounds", line), os.path.join("sounds", os.path.splitext(line)[0] + '.wav'))
```